# verify Popup Alert message text using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, popup, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

```html
<tr>
  <td style="padding: 15px 5px 0 0;" colspan="2">
    <input class="LoginButton2" type="button" value="Login" name="login">events=Object { click=[1]}handle=function()
  </td>
</tr>
```

When I click on the button it shows an error message in a popup alert message box. I want to verify the text from the allert message box. The problem is when I click on the button it does not show me the popup window in selenium webdriver.

Comment: Thanks for the response i tired to click the button using byCssSelector, Xpath, Class and so on but it does not work. My code is     driver.findElement(ByClassName.className("LoginButton2")).click();  driver.findElement(ByXpath.xpath("//div[2]/div[3]/div/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/input")).click();

Comment: When it does not work, what goes wrong? Does the website just continue as if the button had not been clicked, or does the script throw an exception?

Comment: Manually when i click the button the button call a function and it checks some condition. According to the condition it will show message box. The problem is when i try to click the button using selenium web driver it does not show me the message box according to the function.  My code for selenium is driver.findElement(ByXPath.xpath("//div[2]/div[3]/div/form/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input")).sendKeys("sdafsd#@#gfg");
  driver.findElement(ByXPath.xpath("//div[2]/div[3]/div/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys("sda");
  driver.findElement(By.className("LoginButton2")).click();